# Adding "pause" to the Image Slider 

Tags: javascript, jquery

Best way to add pause button in this jQuery image slider? I want to add Pause on clicking the orange square shapes button which is working as a timer in my image slider.

Here is the link with what I tried.

http://jsfiddle.net/QNZDX/4/

For better understanding I am adding the reference site, Here we can find the pause functionality as clicking the orange square shapes.
https://store.sap.com/sap/cpa/repository/store/sapstore/US/default.html

This reference site works only in Mozilla Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

Your post does not contain a question, but I'm guessing you're wanting to change the code in the jsfiddle to add the pause.

The basic mechanism would be check in the onclick if **timer** is 0 (or null). If so, start the timer. Else clear the timer, and set it to null.

Comment: Hai have you checked the reference link

Comment: Little changes to my code is needed. Have to add the functionality of pause to the existing code